# backspace key not working in aptana

Tags: aptana

I've just downloaded Aptana 3.2.2 but, while editing, my backspace key is not working. I've searched on many forums, but I didn't find the issue. I'm on Ubuntu Precise, and I don't have the mouse middle-button pressed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: does the backspace key work in normal eclipse?

Comment: No, it doesn't work in eclipse too.

Comment: Does it work in any java application?

Comment: I tried w/ Metis Dictionary, it works in it.

Comment: Does the backspace key just not work in the code editor of eclipse? Or other dialogs, like new project or find/replace as well?

Comment: it doesn't work just in the editor.

Comment: Have you tried using eclipse off a live CD?

Comment: No, but I understood that it's because I use Aptana **after** a quite long time from when I start up the computer, and at that time other things in Ubuntu get screwed up (like it doesn't select files when I click on, or it doesn't seem to work when I try to press the mouse right button). I don't know why it happens, but from now I will use Aptana when the computer is fresher. thx

Answer (score 2):

I have the same the problem. I solved that by creating a new file (I think it works with any type) and when I had to set a name for it, I pressed backspace.

After that I cancelled the process, and backspace was working as always in the code editor.

Answer (score 0):

Not creating a file but resetting the perspective solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way (Eclipse Mars):

*Window > Preferences > General > Key*,

select the *Command Delete Previous*,

in the combo bindings select *Backspace*,

*Apply*.